# How to check a given Type is a certain object using reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection

Suppose there is the code

```
sealed trait SomeTrait
case class SomeClass() extends SomeTrait
case object SomeObject extends SomeTrait
```

And then the `someTraitType: Type` is obtained via reflection.

To check that `someTraitType` is the type of `SomeClass` it can be done easily `someTraitType =:= typeOf[SomeClass]`.

The question is how can `someTraitType` be checked that is `SomeObject`?

And a following question, can the `SomeObject` instance be obtained from having corresponding `Type` so a simple `==` can be performed?

Comment: `SomeObject.type`?

Comment: By trial and error found the answer to the second question: 
`val universeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)` and then `universeMirror.reflectModule(someTraitType.termSymbol.asModule).instance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful when using `TypeTag` from `scala.reflect.runtime.universe._` to check for type equality.

Consider following checks

```scala
def isSomeClass[T <: SomeTrait: TypeTag](t: T) = {
  typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[SomeClass]
}

def isSomeObject[T <: SomeTrait: TypeTag](t: T) = {
  typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[SomeObject.type]
}
```

The above methods seem to work with following setup

```scala
val s1 = SomeClass()
val s2 = SomeObject

println(isSomeClass(s1)) //prints true
println(isSomeObject(s2)) //prints true
```

However the checks fail when compiler "forgets" types of `s1` and `s2`.

```scala
val s1: SomeTrait = SomeClass()
val s2: SomeTrait = SomeObject

println(isSomeClass(s1)) //prints false
println(isSomeObject(s2)) //prints false
```

The better way is to use `s1.isInstanceOf[SomeClass]` or `s2.isInstanceOf[SomeObject.type]` that works in both cases.